# Use of "in" vs. "During"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Which is more correct to use here? During or in? A PhD and MA holder are having a disagreement.

> During 1966, the program expanded to Gulkana and Wolverine glaciers in Alaska (Meier and others, 1971) and more recently to Montana’s Sperry Glacier [**during**]  [**in**] 2005 (Clark and others, 2017) .

Comment: https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/preps_during-in.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use "in".

When you use "during", you're emphasizing the action, and mentioning the period of time in which it occurred.

When you use "in", you're emphasizing the time period when the action occurred.

Since the quoted statement seems to be focusing on what happened in each year, "in" is more appropriate.